Vercel Speed insights failed to compile
I am trying to implement speed insights on a Vercel deployment and when building it's giving me the following error:
Failed to compile.
./node_modules/@vercel/speed-insights/dist/next/index.mjs
Module not found: Can't resolve 'next/navigation.js' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@vercel/speed-insights/dist/next'

I've installed the necessary dependencies in my project using
yarn add @vercel/speed-insights

and have included the SpeedInsights component in _app.tsx with the following code:
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/global.css';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { Analytics } from '@vercel/analytics/react'
import { SpeedInsights } from '@vercel/speed-insights/next';

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const onClickAnywhere = () => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"
          key="viewport"
          maximum-scale="1"
        />
      </Head>

      <div
        className="text-light-foreground dark:text-dark-foreground min-w-max text-xs md:min-w-
        full md:text-base"
        onClick={onClickAnywhere}
      >
        <main className="bg-light-background dark:bg-dark-background w-full h-full p-2">
          <Component {...pageProps} inputRef={inputRef} />
        </main>
      </div>
      <Analytics />
      <SpeedInsights />
    </>
  );
};

Any help would be appreciated

were you able to find solution?

I encountered the same issue, and I did add a next package in my project.
yarn add next

or
pnpm i next

And my console stopped complaining that. However, I got another error in my browser when I ran it. So that, I don't think it provides smooth support for a general Vue project.

Maybe you could try this: import { SpeedInsights } from '@vercel/speed-insights/react'; instead of "import { SpeedInsights } from '@vercel/speed-insights/next';"  (line 5 of your last piece of code)
